# Plot a 1x16 cell variable

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a variable table that is defined as a `1x16 cell` I want to plot the values in the table. What is the command to do so? The variable name is `result_table`

I have tried

```
plot(result_table)
```

but that did not work

Comment: What is “a 1x16 cell” is it one cell of a cell array that has a 1x16 numeric array in it? Is it a 1x16 cell array? If so, what is in each cell? See [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your cell is like this `result_table = {1,2,3}`

An easy way to plot these three elements is to make them a matrix.
So you can do:

```
A = cell2mat( result_table )
plot(A)
```

[Matlab Reference](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) for cell2mat.

[Matlab Reference](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html) for cell array.